# Suppose f : R → R is continuous. Let λ be a positive real number, and assume that for every x ∈ R and a > 0, f(ax) = a^λf(x).

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous. Let $\lambda$ be a positive real number, and assume that for every $x \in \mathbb R$ and $a > 0$, $f(ax) = a^\lambda f(x)$.

a) Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

b) If $\lambda=1$, $f$ is differentiable at $0$ if and only if $f$ is linear.

To show that $f$ is differentiable at $0$

I consider quotient $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$ and I know that $f(0)=0$

but how can I find $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$ ?

Comment: Use the fact that $f(x) = x^\lambda f(1)$.

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't a general condition on $\lambda$ of $\lambda \geq 1$?

Comment: actually λ has to be greater than or equal to 0

Comment: Henry W- that's what I though first, but how can I verify that ?

Comment: @dlalz, then it is not true in general. Set $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$. This function satisfies the (homogeneity) condition, but is certainly not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Also I am suspicious of the fact that you want to prove differentiability in a) regardless of $\lambda$, but then want to show in b) that when $\lambda=1$ differentiability is equivalent to linearity? Perhaps you mean that $f$ is linear iff $\lambda=1$, which is trivial?

Comment: actually, question is that show that f is differntiable at 0 if λ is greater than or equal to 1 and not at 0 when λ<1

Comment: If what Henry W said is right, result follows trivially. In fact, I am not sure f(x)=x^λf(1) is true given homogeneity